# has_many ,through association Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Hello I need help to create a structure for my database (PostgreSQL)

I want to create a collection(query) that can get all the rooms of a particular flat of a building .eg.

```
biulding.find(1).flats.find(1).rooms.
```

How can I structure my association to archive that?

Thanks

Here are the models

```
class Building < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :flats
  has_many :rooms, through: :flat
end


 class Flat < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :building
  has_many :rooms
end




class Room < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :flat
  belongs_to :building
end
```

#### schema

```
create_table "buildings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
   .....
  end

------------------

create_table "flats", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "number"
    t.bigint "building_id"
    t.bigint "room_id"
    t.index ["building_id"], name: "index_flats_on_building_id"
    t.index ["room_id"], name: "index_flats_on_room_id"
  end


-------------------------------


create_table "rooms", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "number"
    t.bigint "flat_id"
    t.bigint "building_id"
    t.index ["building_id"], name: "index_rooms_on_building_id"
    t.index ["flat_id"], name: "index_rooms_on_flat_id"
  end
```

Comment: Hi @foliwe82, You're asking for creating tables?

Answer (score 1):

What's the starting point? If you have the flat, you can do `flat.rooms` or `Room.where(flat: flat)` or `Room.where(flat_id: id)`. If you have the building, you can do `Building.find(1).rooms` if you have a `has_many :rooms, through: :flats`.

Comment: Thanks. Another question. How can I query to know the number of rooms and flats in the building

Answer (score 1):

Your associations are fine to do what you're asking.
If you want to get rooms for a given flat, you can do : `Flat.find(id).rooms` or `flat.rooms` if you've already set a variable named *flat*.

edit: I can't reply to comment due to reputation limitation, so I reply here.

> Thanks. Another question. How can I query to know the number of rooms and flats in the building

You can do that by adding the `.count` method to your request. Like `flat.rooms.count` or `building.flats.count`.

Comment: Thanks. Another question. How can I query to know the number of rooms and flats in the building

Comment: Agree with carrion. I suggest reading the [Active Record docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html), it's a huge library. You can also check the available methods by doing something like `flat.rooms.methods - Object.methods` (there are a lot of methods which can contribute to the noise).

Answer (score 0):

Association seems fine whether it is for building to flat to rooms and vice versa.

Collection Query, it would list all the data corresponding to a particular building and particular flat:

```
Building.where(id: 1).joins(:flats).first.rooms.where("flats.flat_id = ?",1)
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: i get this error `ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :flat in model Building` when i test your above query in the rails console

Comment: Change the through name to has_many :rooms, through: :flats ("s" added after flat as has_many association is defined with name flats)